# GStreamer pipeline to show an RTSP stream

Tags: video, gstreamer, rtsp

I am pretty new to Gstreamer.

I need to write a video client able to stream data from an RTSP source using GStreamer. I configured VLC to stream a video I have on my laptop using RTSP and I want to create a pipeline to get that stream and show it. I tried using `playbin` and everything works fine. The point is that I need to fine tune the latency used to stream the video but it seems I cannot do that with playbin.

I tried `rtspsrc` because it allows to work on the latency but I don't know how to show the video on any window. That's the pipeline I created:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://localhost:8554/test latency=300 ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

I get the error "streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)".

I tried different pipelines after deeply looking on the internet but I definitely miss something. How can I write a gstreamer pipeline to show a video from RTSP?

The final goal is to have a pipeline which can be adjustable at least in terms of latency, so I have two choices:

- set the latency of playbin element, if possible. (This element correctly shows the video)
- Show the video with the correct pipeline since rtspsrc allows me to set the latency.

I use Xubuntu 16.04, gstreamer-tools-1.0 (used 0.10 as well) and the video I stream with VLC has mp4 extension.

Answer (score 10):

you can adjust the latency by setting the right property and using playbin component:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin uri=rtsp://localhost:8554/test uridecodebin0::source::latency=300
```

Hope you find this useful :)

Answer (score 10):

Assume the rtsp stream is h264 format, use explicit h264 decoder and encoder to parse the stream. Use videoconvert and videoscale to change the frame shape.

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://localhost:8554/test latency=100 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! autovideosink
```

Answer (score 1):

`playbin` does have a `latency` option last time I have checked. Note that its scale is different from the one of `rtspsrc`. `rtspsrc` is in milliseconds while `playbin` is in nanoseconds. It may still not go below a certain threshold - depending on the input video requirements (vbv buffer limitations).

For your `rtspsrc` pipeline you probably miss a `videoconvert` or `autovideosonvert` element right before the `autovideosink`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I got the solution with the answer above. But I am still interested in the second solution with `rtsp`. I tried with both `videoconvert` and `autovideoconvert` but I don't see anything. The pipeline seems to be correct tough. I don't get any error message. Do I need other elements in my pipeline? Thanks!

Comment: export GST_DEBUG=3 and see the logs whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to get this work and was successful on a raspberry pi 3 so I thought "Well since that was so easy I'll try it on the rpi4" Followed the same steps to get gstream installed but when running the command:

gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://localhost:8554/test latency=100 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! autovideosink

It looks like a thermal camera. Still works on the rpi3 just fine though. Not sure what would be making the difference here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was receiving a video stream with impressive latency from an android smartphone(server) to an nvidia jetson nano(client) for later inference processing and the following string worked:

```
pipeline = "rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:admin@192.xxx.x.xx:xxxx latency=0 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! appsink"
```

After replacing the "omxh264dec" decoder with "avdec_h264" in the pipeline they disappeared the following deprecations:

(

```
python3:10659): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 22:47:22.966: gst_caps_is_empty: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed

(python3:10659): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 22:47:22.966: gst_caps_truncate: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed

(python3:10659): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 22:47:22.966: gst_caps_fixate: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed

(python3:10659): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 22:47:22.966: gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed

(python3:10659): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 22:47:22.966: gst_structure_get_string: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed

(python3:10659): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 22:47:22.966: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed
```

I hope i was helpful

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).